# Uninstalled macOS Sierra installer but corresponding disk space(~4.88GB) not freed

Tags: applications, install, macos

I had downloaded macOS Sierra(~4.88GB) from App Store to create a bootable for a friend on my Macbook Air. After doing that successfully, I deleted the macOS Sierra Installer app from Applications directory. But my Drive size was not freed by 4.88GBs instead deleting it freed only 1GB. Are there any residual files I need to remove manually?

Comment: Did you empty the Trash?

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, I did.

Comment: @Tetsujin I found the where the problem was. I opened Disk Utility and there was a disk with the name Apple RID... which was occupying around 5GB which must have been created by the macOS Sierra installer. I ejected the disk and restarted my laptop, and the memory was freed. Finally got back the held up memory. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with a disk image with the name Apple RID... created by the macOS Sierra installer which did not get ejected when macOS installer was deleted and was occupying around 5.5GBs and wasn't visible anywhere except in Disk Utility.

After ejecting that disk using Disk Utility and restarting the laptop, the memory which was held up got freed.